# What difference does it make who takes the shot on the traitor?

Tags: mass-effect-3

At the end of the *Priority: Citadel* mission a stand off forms and Shepard had managed to convince the other Spectre to support him, when the traitor pulled a gun on the Asari Councillor. A red/renegade interrupt opportunity popped up, which I took, and Shepard shoots the traitor.

I was interested to see what could have happened, so I rewound the game to a previous save just to see what the result of missing the interrupt is, and the other Spectre takes the shot instead, with what appears to be the same immediate results.

What I want to know is are there any long term differences depending on whom out of Shepard and the other Spectre takes that shot and kills the traitor?

Comment: I find the renegade popup annoying, it's sudden and insistent, I've clicked every single one so far without really having a chance to think about what I'm doing, and I sometimes regret my decision!

Comment: @fredley I think that's sort of the point - you make a snap decision based on your gut. Sometimes you realise the consequences were not what you thought. I like the uncertainty of the system :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No long term ramifications. However if you are cruel to the other Spectre beforehand they can be killed off in this mission for believing the traitor instead of trusting you.